# Tiny aliens spaceships flying in Kid room like Floogals spaceships Floogals (2016)

Tags: story-identification, aliens, spaceship

Tiny aliens spaceships flying in Kid  room like Floogals spaceships [Floogals (2016)](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=1793092660711546)
[image]

Tiny aliens spaceships. Animated show where small toy sized spaceships flying in a kid’s room. I saw it on a kids' animated show on a TV channel in the 80s or 90s.

Kid finding real tiny aliens spaceships like small toy sized in his room Hiding among the toys. flying in their house and the tiny spaceships fight with one another. The children intervene to stop the fighting and hide the spaceships in the room together with toys.

special scene
The child tied the evil spaceships to prevent them from attacking.
spaceships are trying to escape in vain

[So, one of those tiny alien spaceships has flown into your house. Now what?](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-07517-4)

[Dinky Doors: tiny alien spaceship has crash landed in Cambridge](https://www.cambridgeindependent.co.uk/whats-on/dinky-flying-object-crash-lands-in-cambridge-9075966/)

It was like *[Computer Warriors: The Adventure Begins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vslzh_jTmEE)* but with alien spaceships.

A similar spaceships to this was in the [Dinosaucers (1987) episode *That Shrinking Feeling*](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x52rykf) and similar battle to this was in [Computer Warriors: The Adventure Begins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vslzh_jTmEE)

[Aliens Ate My Homework (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6624126/)

[Small spaceships shorts (2009)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1100119/)

Animated show with small toy sized spaceships flying in a kid's room.
Tiny spaceships Battle
I saw it on a TV channel. Probably European cartoon

[image]

Similar storyline to

- Dinosaucers (1987) episode [*That Shrinking Feeling*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1749369/)
- Transformers (1984) episode [*Child's Play*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808819/)
- Challenge of the GoBots (1984) [*Cy-Kill's Shrinking Ray*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1064288/)
- [*Computer Warriors*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0402935/) (1990)

Comment: I'd swear we had another question like this, with a kid finding tiny spaceships flying through their room, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I thought so too. Perhaps OP deleted it?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I've commented on this in chat (with links).

Comment: Please stop making pointless edits (e.g. adding/removing whitespace) just to bump the post. Only make edits that actually improve the post i.e. add information, correct mistakes etc. You've been warned about this on previous posts.

Comment: TheLethalCarrot
 Sorry an error

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Is there a animated cartoon like this Tiny aliens without spaceships

Comment: @bpvwvqd: *Space Jungle*, for one. Why do you ask?

Comment: Reminds me a bit of [Batteries Not Included](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batteries_Not_Included)

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern
 Really close to it 
but cartoon 
And group Tiny aliens spaceships In the child's room, they fight each other