# Need help identifying 80s/90s animated movie about computer viruses

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching an animated movie aimed towards children about animated computer viruses trying to take over. Anti-viruses were flying around on little ships and trying to stop the invading viruses. There were scenes where they escaped the computer and flew around the child's bedroom. Many scenes were shown from inside the computer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Comment: Sure it was a movie, not a series?

Comment: FuzzyBoots was correct. It is Computer Warriors (1990) I had a VHS tape of this when I was younger and I just couldn't remember what it was called. Brings back memories :) Looks like it was just a pilot of an unsold series. It seemed longer than 22 minutes in my memory.

Comment: Your question has been closed as a Duplicate. That doesn't mean it's a bad question, just one we've had answered before. You will still get points for votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from my answer at ['90s cartoon involving characters flying out of a PC](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/272419/23243)

It sounds like it might be the pilot episode of *[Computer Warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Warriors)*, based off of a toyline by Mattel in the early 90s.

> At a government facility named Parallax, a massive supercomputer core suffers a power surge due to “human error” of one its operators. The surge triggers a core dump, which unleashes four A.I. programs that are transformed into dangerous Viruses, which are ejected into the Bitstream (an analog for the Internet). These Viruses are Megahert, the leader and dominant A.I.; Indexx, his advisor who has access to information data; Null, a dimwitted lackey who follows Megahert without question; Minus, an unstable minion who thirsts for power. These four seek to return to Parallax to use its systems to seize the Bitstream and use it to take over all the world's computers.
>
> In response, the Parallax Core Processing Unit generates four unique “anti-viral” programs, to stop the Viruses before they can do any damage. These "Computer Warriors" are Romm, the command program and leader; Skannar, who can track the Viruses trail through the Bitstream; Gridd, a diagnostic program with skills to keep himself and the others operating, and Micronn, a statistical program which has access to the data banks at Parallax, to aid their mission.
>
> Riding on Circuit Gliders, the Computer Warriors chase the Viruses down, but the Viruses manage to escape by use of a Telecom Port; which explodes after they damage it. Romm believes them neutralized, but the Viruses survived by being transported into the physical world outside of computers: in a suburban family's home. The Telecom Port is repaired by Parallax—after the CPU detects Indexx accessing one of its data banks—and the Warriors head back to transfer through it, ending up in the same house. Both the Viruses and Warriors soon learn they can scan and adapt camouflage shells that look like ordinary, everyday objects; which allow them to continue their battle to either capture or destroy the other side.

### Computer Warriors: The Adventure Begins

### Flying out of the computer

[image: The Computer Warriors flying out of the computer on their Circuit Gliders]

Found via a mention in [Tiny aliens spaceships flying in Kid room like Floogals spaceships Floogals (2016)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258864/tiny-aliens-spaceships-flying-in-kid-room-like-floogals-spaceships-floogals-201)